# jQuery mouseleave from child elements

Tags: jquery, mouseover, mouseleave

Here's the dealio: I have a table. When you mouse over it, jQuery adds some editing buttons. When you mouse out of the table, they go away. The problem is that if you move the mouse into the table, then over the button, and THEN out, they stay in place. How can I fix this?

JsFiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/kthornbloom/LHZdd/1/

Simplified code:

```
$(document.body).on("mouseover", ".edit table", function (e) {
    $('.jr-columnmodifier, .jr-rowmodifier').remove();
    $('<div class="button"></div>').appendTo(this);
});

$(document.body).on("mouseleave", ".edit table, .button", function (e) {
    $('.button').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have an answer for *why*, but `mouseenter` instead of `mouseover` seems to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/P3FMQ/

```
$(document.body).on("mouseenter", ".edit table", function (e) {
```

Comment: Very curious why changing the mouse-in state would effect the mouse-out behavior. But yes, this seems to work.

Comment: I do know that `mouseover` fires every time you mouse over any child of the element with the handler attached to it, and `mouseenter` only once. Perhaps that matters here.